# Is creating unit tests in a separate project the correct approach for Android?

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit

This description of how to get started with testing in Android appears inconsistent:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/testing/testing_android.html

It says:

> A test project is a directory or Eclipse project in which you create
>   the source code, manifest file, and other files for a test package.
>   The Android SDK contains tools for Eclipse with ADT and for the
>   command line that create and update test projects for you. The tools
>   create the directories you use for source code and resources and the
>   manifest file for the test package.

However, then it says:

> You can create a test project anywhere in your file system, but the
>   best approach is to add the test project so that its root directory
>   tests/ is at the same level as the src/ directory of the main
>   application's project. This helps you find the tests associated with
>   an application.

Then it shows a project structure where all of your tests are under your main project and not a separate project. Yet, if you use the ADT plugin, it will create a separate project. Which is correct, or best practice -- a separate project for unit tests, or the same project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may be possible to create unit tests in a seperate project, but the way I've done it is just using a different package.

This allows you to reference any classes you may need easily while creating your assert fields.

The way I do it is have a package called com..Data.Tests and use the following to define my tests:

```
public class AddressValidationTest extends
    ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<InitialActivity>
```

This allows you to keep everything within one project.

Hope this helps!

EDIT:  It may be possible your confusion is coming from the Java terminology of projects vs. packages vs. classes.  I think in this case, when they say a "project" they are referring to a stand-alone class that is able to run a unit test.

EDIT2:
You shouldn't need more than one manifest.
Include any test activities in the manifest with the following:

```
<uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />  

<instrumentation android:label="All Tests"
    android:name="com.App.Data.Tests.MyInstrumentationTestRunner"
    android:targetPackage="com.App.UI" />
```

Comment: Can u write how do u set up tests in the same project. I cant have more than one AndroidManifest.xml - it shows an error.

Comment: "when they say a "project" they are referring to a stand-alone class that is able to run a unit test" Really? That would be a strange way to use that term. I would just call it a class :)

Comment: "Include any test activities in the manifest with the following:" -- Thank you for the second edit. That actually coincides with what Labeb P was saying about including something extra in the manifest. Can you tell me where the best place to find more documentation on your particular approach? Maybe a blog post?

Comment: I still got sth like that:   Test run failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException'

Comment: The way Labeeb is demonstrating is also valid.  I simply prefer to keep my unit tests in the same project as my "actual project".  It speeds up development, and you can exclude the code for a final build.  If you are not familiar with these methods, you may want to follow Labeeb's methodology.  As far as the java.lang.classnotfoundexception goes, you are likely not referencing the class you actually want to test.  Try stepping through the code and seeing exactly where it fails.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because after reviewing some sample code from the SDK, it looks like the "expectation" at some point was that the tests would be under the main project. It seems the ADT plugin simply confused the matter by how it sets up a separate test project.

Answer (score 7):

> Is creating unit tests in a separate project the correct approach for
>   Android?

**My opinion**, Yes it is the best approach
If using same project there will be some extra codes in your `manifest`, you need to add extra class in your src.
While if you create a separate project it will not effect our main project code 
And by functionality ways both will work in the same way.
So why going for a confusion :)

EDIT: for using same project you need to add the following in you manifest file

```
<manifest>
    <!-- For doing JUnit test--->
    <instrumentation
        android:targetPackage="com.your.package.where.testclasses"
        android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner" />
        <application ...>
            <activity..>
            <!-- For doing JUnit test -->
            <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
        </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: I think it would be possible to use code coverage tools if they are in one project.

Comment: Do you mean you need to add stuff into your manifest and your source tree in order to support unit tests if it's in the same project?

Comment: @Greg. Yes we can use code converge tools. But what I think was, both are doing same think so why we need go for a confusion _my personal opinion only_

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, creating separate project for test cases is good go.
Especially if your project need earlier version of JRE. For Android projects this may not apply, but for embedded Java projects where it needs older JREs.

As most testing frameworks needs at least JDK 1.5 or above, creating separate projects for the test classes is the only solution.