# Unit testing Android application logic

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit

Looking to write some tests for my application, I stumbled upon the [Android testing pages](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/index.html). After a fairly long read, it quickly became apparent that the only thing that I could possibly get out of it is information about how to test the UI/Activities. What I really want is the way to test my logic with simply `ant test`, preferably without even involving the device. I should mention at this stage that I am not using Eclipse and it's quite saddening that 99% of the Java resources on Android assume people do so.

In any case, trying to get anything at all running, I played along with the tutorial as much as I could. It asks that a `tests` directory is made on the same level as `src`. Sure, even if every other of their pages implies that the test-project is a completely separate entity. While in the top level project directory, I ran
`android create test-project -m /path/to/my/project/ -n MyProjectTest -p tests`. It's worth mentioning that they are very inconsistent with saying how they want things to be set up [as seen on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859807/is-creating-unit-tests-in-a-separate-project-the-correct-approach-for-android). Visiting the directory, I spot the default testing file. Here's where the issues begin.

To my understanding, testing is done as follows: build application, install; go to tests, build tests, install; run tests from the tests directory using `ant test` or start them directly using `adb shell am instrument`. This worked fine. I however have no desire to test the activity but just the logic (which doesn't access any Views/Activities).

Changing the default test to extend `AndroidTestClass` seemed to have work for a while. The tests were being ran but there were caveats: cleaning `tests` with `ant clean` also cleaned the project directory (`../tests`) so it took forever to build tests in a clean environment (which is necessary because `ant debug` seems terrible at detecting changes) but it worked and I was happy.

Few more tests later, I get `java.lang.VerifyError` on my only test class. Googling and Stacking around, it boiled down to either something wrong with external libs or something wrong with my class path. I'm not using any external `.jar`s so it's probably my path.

In any case, here is my question:
what is The Proper Way™ to unit test logic in Android applications with JUnit? I can't find any resources at all concerning this: all resources are either for testing the UI parts or for unit testing ordinary applications.

How can I unit test my logic *only*? This shouldn't even require a device to run on given that I don't need to use any parts of Android. Where do I place the tests? What do I need to change so that running `ant test` in my project directory will then run those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A long mess-around later and I have managed to do it.

First of all, I have ignored any project creation using `adb`.

Imagine my package is called `com.foo.bar`. I created `tests` in `src/com/foo/bar/tests`. In there, write your regular JUnit tests. Make sure you put `package com.foo.bar.tests` in your test classes. Here's an example class:

```
package com.foo.bar.tests;

import com.foo.bar.baz.Foo;

import org.junit.*;
import junit.framework.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;


public class MyTests extends TestCase {

    public void testSomething() {
        Foo testFoo= new Foo();
        assertEqual(testFoo.getBar(), 1);
    }
}
```

Next is the case of having the tests run with `ant test`. To achieve this, add the following to your `AndroidManifest.xml` just before the last closing bracket (`</manifest>`):

```
<instrumentation android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
                 android:targetPackage="com.foo.bar"
                 android:label="Tests for com.foo.bar"/>
```

You also need

```
<uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
```

added to your `<application>` section.

I can't figure out what would need changing to test locally and not on the device but this is 75% of the answer and hopefully will be of help to someone like me in the future.

EDIT:
It's possible to just shadow the original `ant test` behaviour by adding the following below the last import in `build.xml`:

```
   <target name="test" >
       <junit>
           <!-- all your junit stuff here -->
       </junit>
   </target>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/) — it lets you avoid much of Google's nightmare of a testing solution.

A good article from Square on the subject: [The Resurrection of Testing for Android](http://corner.squareup.com/2013/04/the-resurrection-of-testing-for-android.html).